# 2 sidebars with middle col-md centered bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How can I make my website look like this using bootstrap? I want 2 sidebars with 300px on both sides of container. The middle column I wanna be centered on the middle of page.

```
   <!-- this is my middle column -->
    <div class="container content profile">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Begin Content -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/irIrU.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, Hope it will helps you.

```css
.mid-col{
  background: red;
}
.left-section{
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
.right-section{
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
}
.profile .col-md-12.mid-col{
  width: calc(100% - 600px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) {
  .profile .col-md-12.mid-col ,
  .left-section,
  .right-section{
        width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container content profile">
      <div class="row">
            <!-- left section -->
            <div class="left-section pull-left">
                  L
            </div>
            <!-- left section -->
            <div class="col-md-12 mid-col">
                  M
            </div>
            <!-- right section -->
            <div class="left-section pull-right">
                  R
            </div>
            <!-- right section -->
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the row from container?

Comment: Work`s great. Thank you.

Comment: And if I need this scenario too: only 2 columns, left sidebar and middle, but the middle to be in center of page and the left sidebar behind?

Comment: then remove right section,  and adjust the `mid-col` width value

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cPcA/777/)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 "
         style="height:600px;background:blue">
             <h4> Left sidebar</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 "
         style="height:600px;background:yellow">
             <h4 style="text-align:center;"> Content</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 "
         style="height:600px;background:green">
             <h4> Right sidebar</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On middle I want to use the html code from the question and wanna be centered in the middle of page.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle you can have a look at it. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cPcA/777/

Comment: @Steevan but @Ion saying the fix width `300px`